# How to parse didReceiveUserInfo userInfo parameter? A __NSSingleObjectArrayI

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to parse the `userInfo` variable of:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
```

if I `print(userInfo)` I see:

```
["session": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x608000011220>(
{
    created = "2017-01-20 22:13:45 +0000";
    device = "watchOS";
    id = 8;
    synced = 0;
    "person_id" = 17;
}
)
]
```

How do I actually parse `userInfo` so I can get the individual properties? I attempted to convert this object to a NSDictionary but failed.

EDIT:

I attempted to convert "session" to an NSDictionary like so:

```
if let loggedSession = userInfo["session"] as? NSDictionary {
```

However, this failed. So my problem is accessing the data of "session". I was hoping to convert this to a dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your output, the value for key `"session"` is an `NSArray` containing a single object which is an `NSDictionary`, so you may need to retrieve one element from the array:

```
if let sessions = userInfo["session"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    //You may need to retrieve one element from the array
    let sessionInfo = sessions[0]
    //Use `sessionInfo` as [String: Any]
    print(sessionInfo["created"]) //->Optional(2017-01-20 22:13:45 +0000)
    //...
}
```